# Force Mail.app to use a certain email account for certain recipients?

Tags: macos, mac, mail.app, email, mojave

When I email a certain person I always want my outgoing email to be on  my email account X rather than account Y. For example, I always want to send Bob email messages via Google Gmail rather than Yahoo Mail.

Is there a way in Mail.app for macOS Mojave to enforce this rule, so I use the right email account for that particular recipient?

Comment: `Mail` > `Preferences` > `Composing`; `Addressing` - `Send message from:` and select `Select Account of selected mailbox` to reply using the same account used to receive the email from Bob (presumably to your Gmail address). Newer macos should have 'Automatically selected best account'.

Comment: From the left pane, Mailboxes -> Inbox select the provider first. Then, when clicking to Compose messages it starts with the  selected provider in "From" field of your mail.

Comment: Mail.app doesn't support automatic sender email address selection based on recipient. I guess it could be somehow solved with an Automator service, but it would be cumbersome at best. As a workaround, you could set `Mail` > `Preferences` > `Composing; Addressing - Send message from:` to `Select Account of selected mailbox`, as explained by user90735 above, and have multiple Viewer Windows open, each one for one of your email addresses. You could then select the  appropriate Viewer Window before composing a message.